# IIS ISAPI Extension + How to Modify HTTP response body

Tags: c++, iis, isapi, isapi-extension

On IIS6, I know ISAPI filter can easily do this, but I am trying to do the same in an ISAPI Extension.

I would like to let IIS handle a request, but be able to Append some string to the response.

Is there a callback that would let me modify the http response before it's sent?

Such as:

Client request: index.html
ISAPI extension gets called, and forward the request to IIS with: HSE_REQ_EXEC_URL
ISAPI entension gets called again, with the response, modify it, and send it.

Just can't seem to find any ServerSupportFunction that does that :(

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to use an output (send_raw_data) filter.

Well, OK, there's a sneaky way to simulate this, but it has perf implications - you can manually request the document from the server using winhttp or something. Tons of code to get it right, though.